# CPU time limit exceeded (core dumped) meaning

Tags: coredump

When I solve some question in Interview Street, sometimes a message comes "CPU time limit exceeded (core dumped)" when we fail to pass a test case.

What is the actual meaning of this message?

[image: This is the message]

Comment: So what part don't you understand? That the OS can impose run time limits? What a core dump is? That a core dump implies termination of the process?

Comment: What is the meaning of "CPU Time limit exceeded"? This question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means your code exceeded time limit for the contest.

Check the scoring rule on their website.

Answer (score -1):

```
unlimit cpu
```

Is this what you need?